# Is the ADO Recordset.CacheSize property meaningful for a client-side cursor?

Tags: ado

**If I have an ADO `Connection` with `CursorLocationType.adUseClient` and I use it to open a `Recordset`, then does setting the `Recordset.CacheSize` property have any effect?**

From [CacheSize Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/cachesize-property-ado?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Use the CacheSize property to control how many records to retrieve at one time into local memory from the provider.

And from [The Significance of Cursor Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/the-significance-of-cursor-location?view=sql-server-ver15):

> In ADO, call for a client-side cursor by using the adUseClient CursorLocationEnum. With a non-keyset client-side cursor, the server sends the entire result set across the network to the client computer.

It seems to me that setting `CacheSize` will have no effect for a client-side cursor, because the records are already in local memory. But I can't find any official documentation that explicitly says this. I can only find blog posts like [this one](https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/121298-1.shtml) that says:

> We will be using ClientSide cursors ... The CacheSize tells ADO to cache N number of rows on the cursor. Since we chose to have 10 records per page, I set the cache size to 10. ADO will grab the first 10 records, and cache those. It won't hit the database until you request any past the cached limit.

but this seems to contradict "the server sends the entire result set across the network to the client computer."

**So what actually happens?**